# Prevent Visual Studio Code to format some tag as new line

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

I use `<code>` as an inline code styling. Formatting :

```
<p>In Unity if you select "Loop" in <code>AudioSource</code>, the song will loop to beginning when it reaches the very end.</p>
```

Results in :

```
<p>In Unity if you select "Loop" in
<code>AudioSource</code>, the song will loop to beginning when it reaches the very end.</p>
```

The webpage still display fine, but I don't want this new line in my HTML file how to exclude some tags?

`"html.format.extraLiners": "head, body, /html",` seems to be for "including" not excluding.

Answer (score 3):

Oh.. never mind. It's `"html.format.unformatted": "code"`

(I swear I tried that, but trying again and it works...)